# Evaluating this "$\infty-\infty$" limit including definite integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I need to calculate a limit like
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left[xP(x)P\left(\frac{x}{1+r}\right)-\int^x_{(1+r)\bar{\alpha}}P(w)P\left(\frac{w}{1+r}\right)dw \right] $$
where $P(\cdot)$ is a cumulative density function(CDF), and $P(0)=0$, $P(\infty)=1$. Both $\bar{\alpha}$ and $r$ are positive. Of course the first term and the second term themselves have no limits but it seems that their difference has a limit.

I have used up all methods that I know to calculate it but still have no idea. Does anyone can calculate it?

Comment: Integration by parts cancels out the first term; that is, the limit becomes $$(1+r)\bar\alpha P(\bar\alpha)P((1+r)\bar\alpha)+\int_{(1+r)\bar\alpha}^\infty \left(w\cdot\frac d{dw}\left[P(w)P\left(\frac w{1+r}\right)\right]\right)\,dw$$

Comment: I see. Many thanks!